# Reversing the probability distribution for falling ball

Tags: probability, conditional-probability, statistical-inference, bayes-theorem

I was reading [this](http://colah.github.io/posts/2014-07-Understanding-Convolutions/#visualizing-convolutions) wonderful piece about convolution, but I could not understand the following:

> Suppose the probability that a ball lands a certain distance x from where it started is f(x). Then, afterwards, the probability that it started a distance x from where it landed is f(−x).
> [image: colah]

It can be intuitively true such that if the distribution of $f(x)$ is concentrated on the right (like a negative skew), then a landed ball probably had been fallen from the left.

However, I tried to wrote this problem in a Bayesian way, but I could not derive the $f(-x)$. Can anyone explain how is this derived with or without Bayes' rule?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some Bayesian analysis might be needed in an extension of this study, but not here, not yet.

This is just a common coordinate transformation in science and engineering.

Denote the starting position as $Y_1$ and the position afterwards as $Y_2$, measured with respect to a certain external reference frame (the two positions are measure in the same reference frame). This external frame doesn't even need to be an absolute (fixed) one, presumably the possible movement of the frame (seemingly just translation and no rotation, no scaling, and no skewing) is already taken care of during the modeling of the displacement distribution $f_X(x)$ that is given.

When one takes the "before" position $Y_1$ as the temporary origin, the displacement **for any** $\pmb Y$ with respect to this origin is $X\equiv Y - Y_1$, including $Y_2\,.~$ For this point $Y_2$ that is of interest, denote $X \equiv Y_2 - Y_1$. 
<sup>usually the word "displacement is used to emphasize that it can be negative, while sometimes people think "difference" is always non-negative.</sup>

Similarly, When one takes the $Y_2$ as the temporary origin, then the displacement with respect to **this origin** is $X' \equiv Y - Y_2$ for any $Y$. Note the symmetry of this definition: the displacement is always defined **with respect to a specific origin** in the same way.

The point $Y_1$ now is of interest, and it's displacement with respect to $Y_2$ is $X' \equiv Y_1 - Y_2 = -X$.

That's it. The quantities being deterministic or stochastic doesn't change how a displacement (coordinate) should be defined. When an (temporary) origin is chosen, it is the "object" $Y_1$ that is chosen, not a value (fixed point) $Y_1 = y_1$ that is chosen. Of course, the chosen object can be degenerate thus fixed, or the object could be auxiliary and doesn't correspond to an actual physical particle.

Comment: Thank you for your detailed response. I understood how you view the problem (at least hopefully), but Why can not we choose a global coordinate system and use Bayes'rule?

Comment: Sure you can, I didn't say anything about one cannot .... just "not here, not yet". This blog is really just a simple convolution. The definition of coordinates comes before any analysis. Bayes rule can come into play when it needs to. At just setting the relations between stuff, what do you need that for?

Comment: When you want to think about "what's that thing about the before-position conditioned on knowing the after-position", you can use Bayes rule, but this is after one has set up the coordinates.